# SquareUp Payment after token nonce generation

Tags: node.js, payment-gateway, square

After generating nonce from squareup payment form to make a payment, we make a call using that token with the help of square client from node.

` const client = new Client({
environment: Environment.Sandbox, // Use Environment.Production for the production environment
accessToken: accessToken,
});

```
        if (client instanceof Client) {
          const response = await client.paymentsApi.createPayment({
            sourceId: token,
            idempotencyKey: Math.random().toString(36).substring(7),
            amountMoney: {
              amount: 100,
              currency: 'USD'
            }
          ;
```

`

This is how i'm doing it

`[ERROR] Error processing payment: adapter is not a function`

This is the error i get after running this function. What can be the reason and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The error was because cloudflare workers didnt support API calls like this. So used the fetch method instead of it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).